# run batch job from a C++ program with parameters

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file

I am very new to C++ programming.
My goal is to run a batch file from a c++ code. For that purpose, I have used crateProcess function and I have sent the batch file name and some parameters to it.
In this case, the batch job is running file. The related code for what I did is:

```
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(fileName.begin(), fileName.end());
    LPCWSTR sw = stemp.c_str();
if (!
    CreateProcess
    (
        TEXT("C:\\Users\\srijani.ghosh\\Desktop\\param 1.bat"),
        NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
        NULL, NULL,
        &si,
        &pi
    )
    ) {
};
```

But, another requirement is that, I need to send some command line arguments to the batch file which the file will read while executing.
Example batch file -

```
@echo hello %1 %2
pause
```

But, I am not sure how can I send this parameters to the batch file in this situation.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Microsoft description of [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The first parameter, lpApplicationName, can be NULL, in which case the executable name must be in the white space–delimited string pointed to by lpCommandLine.

And followed-up example show how to specify arguments

```
LPTSTR szCmdline = _tcsdup(TEXT("C:\\Program Files\\MyApp -L -S"));
CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdline, /* ... */);
```

Also please see Microsoft working example of correct usage of CreateProcess 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx